# Class method to call variable method

Tags: c++, class, syntax, simplify

My current situation is a structure like this :

```
class Foo {
    public:
        void call() {
            b.call();
        }
    private:
        Bar b;
};

class Bar {
    public:
        void call() {
            std::cout << "Hello there" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;

    f.call(); // This calls directly the b.call() function
}
```

Is there a syntax that could directly make the `Foo.call`  function call directly the function inside class stored as a variable ?

Basically, is there a syntax that could do something like :

```
class Foo {
    public:
        void call() -> b.call
    private:
        Bar b;
};
```

Comment: Nope.  What you have is the way you need to do it (ignoring the fact that `Bar` needs to be defined before `Foo` for it to actually compile)

Comment: Isn't `b` `private` for a reason?

Comment: @CinCout Selectively bridging to certain methods on `b` is a fairly common pattern.

Comment: Unrelated: To my knowledge `Bar b;` never made a Lauren `b.call();` doll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about a language-level *delegate* construct. Some languages have built-in support for this, but C++ does not. You have to do it the "hard way" like you have.

If this is a really prevalent thing you could define a macro, but it's usually better to have ugly code than confusing or misleading code.

Comment: I was being overly lazy and wanted to know if it already existed but I guess i'll keep coding properly...

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with being that sort of lazy. For all you knew C++17 threw in exactly this feature.

Comment: The way you did it.

Comment: class Foo {
    public:
            void call() -> b.call
        private:
            Bar b;
    };

Wait, this works ?

Comment: No, I mean the long-form way you did it. The difference is zero characters, `{}` vs. `->`, so I don't know what the fuss is here.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally unnecessary to try and help the compiler like this.  Compilers are very good at optimizing this sort of thing.  You don't need to tell the compiler `Foo::call` is really just a `Bar::call`.  The compiler will figure it out.  Consider a slightly tweaked example:

```
extern void DisplayMessage(char const*);

class Bar {
public:
  void call() {
    DisplayMessage("Hello there");
  }
};

class Foo {
public:
  void call() {
    b.call();
  }
private:
  Bar b;
};

int main() {
  Foo f;

  f.call(); // This calls directly the b.call() function
}
```

When I compile this using Clang 7.0 and -O3, I get the following:

```
main:                                   # @main
    push    rax
    mov     edi, offset .L.str
    call    DisplayMessage(char const*)
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rcx
    ret
```

Notice that the compiler has removed the objects completely and left only a direct call to the `DisplayMessage` function.

Comment: I don't actually see the OP's question being about optimization, rather it is the case that *by definition* `Foo::call` exposes the (otherwise private) `Foo::b.call`.  A language construct for that sort of semantic is not an unreasonable thing to imagine.  (It so happens that it doesn't exist of course).

Comment: Yes.  Given that he accepted an answer along those lines, it seems I misunderstood. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might have shorter code with:

```
class Bar {
public:
    void call() const {
        std::cout << "Hello there" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Foo : private Bar // private is superfluous here, as we use class instead of struct
{
public:
    using Bar::call;
};
```

but composition way with manual forwarding seems more natural.